# where to put :html => { :multipart => true } in form_for & fields_for?

Tags: object, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, form-for

I have a form_for that has a fields_for for a double object form creation. The second object is attachments that has a paperclip (ruby gem) attribute for adding photos attributed to the first object. The box model is being created, but the attachment model is not as far as I can tell. One of my questions is where the multipart => true needs to go, the form_for, fields_for, or both?

Edit: it seems that the box_id cannot be passed through as a param because the box hasn't been created yet. So how do I make the attachment attributed to the box in the controller? I thought

```
@box.attachments.build(params)
```

would make the correct attribution, but that doesn't work.

Do I need to user nested attributes here?

Here is the console log:

```
Processing by BoxesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0vka+nZDc56OdISMctWoJjY8CH+TR20PHBl8oVglD5A=", "box"=>{"user_id"=>"45", "name"=>"asdfasdf", "origin"=>"asdfasdf", "description"=>"asdfasdf"}, "attachment"=>{"box_id"=>"", "screen_shot"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc3d8202990 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140521-11119-37nj3s>, @original_filename="P5110017.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"attachment[screen_shot]\"; filename=\"P5110017.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Share the Love!"}
```

Note that the box_id is blank, yet with the validation in the model I don't get any errors.

Here is my form code:

```
  <%= form_for @box, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>

    <%= f.label :name, "Name" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name, autofocus: true %><br>

    <%= f.label :origin, 'Website' %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :origin %><br>

    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description, cols: "30", rows: "4" %>

    <%= fields_for @attachment do |ff| %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :box_id, :value => @box.id %>
        <%= ff.file_field :screen_shot, id:"attachment", :required => true %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Create!" %>
  <% end %>
```

Here is my controller:

```
class BoxesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @box = Box.new
    @attachment = Attachment.new
  end

  def create
    @box = current_user.boxes.build(boxes_params)
    @attachment = @box.attachments.build(attachment_params)
    if @box.save
      flash[:success] = "Box created"
      redirect_to @box
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error"
      redirect_to 'new'
    end 
  end

  def update
    @box = Box.find(params[:id])
    if @box.update_attributes(boxes_params)
      flash[:success] = "Box updated"
      redirect_to @box
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @box = Box.find(params[:id])
    @box.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Box deleted."
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

    def boxes_params
      params.require(:box).permit(:description, :name, :origin, :attachment)
    end

    def attachment_params
      params.require(:attachment).permit(:screen_shot, :box_id)
    end
end
```

And the box model:

```
  class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
    has_many :attachments, :dependent => :destroy, :limit => 4
    is_impressionable
    validate :attachments_count_within_limit, :on => :create
    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates_presence_of :name
    validates_length_of :description, :maximum => 1000
```

Attachment model:

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :box
  has_attached_file :screen_shot, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :screen_shot, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates :box_id, presence: true
end
```

I had also tried changing the box_controller to create the attachment via

```
@attachment = Attachment.new(attachment_params)
```

but that still did not work.

Comment: Try printing out @box.id in your view and see if it contains the required id.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing out `@box.id` in your view and see if it contains the required `id` and also send your `box_id` along with `:screenshot`

```
def attachment_params
   params.require(:attachment).permit(:box_id, :screen_shot)
end
```

Comment: OK, I had been trying differnt things and I originally did have :box_id in the attachment_params. Otherwise, I think you are o the right track. The box_id doesn't exist on the new page because the box hasn't been created yet. Therefore, it can't get passed as a param.